# slow loader time

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I've installed fresh ubuntu server 16.04 and I have notably slower boot time now. This is NUC 2820 with ssd drive.
After bios start I see blank screen for about 20 seconds before any ubuntu output.

Executed systemd-analyze and it shows next:
`Startup finished in 11.175s (firmware) + 14.277s (loader) + 3.297s (kernel) + 3.451s (userspace) = 32.202s`

I.e. "loader" is most slower part of all. What is it? I guess this is GRUB. How to solve it? I searched about systemd-analyze and everywhere I see that loader takes less than second.

Contents of /etc/default/grub is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 0):

edit the file /etc/init/failsafe.conf 
nano /etc/init/failsafe.conf

comment out the sleeps in the failsafe.conf
eg. previously :-
    $PLYMOUTH message --text="Waiting for network configuration..." || :
    sleep 40
    finally :
    $PLYMOUTH message --text="Waiting for network configuration..." || :
    #sleep 40

Comment: there is no such file at my system. As I see this file is from Upstart, but Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd.